# Neighborhood base at zero in a topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'm reading  a proof of a theorem which characterizes the collections of sets which can serve as a neighborhood base at zero in a topological vector space:
[image][image]

Here are my questions:

> Why "This shows that $\mathcal{N}$ is a neighborhood base at zero" and how this help to prove the uniqueness? I can understand the proof up to the the underscored sentence. But I don't see how to reach that point. (What is the construction of $A$ used for? How does the author show that $U\in\mathcal{N}$ is a neighborhood of zero?)

The definition of a neighborhood base at some point in a topological space I know is as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a neighbourhood base, which is used in the proof, seems to me to be different from the definition you posted. I think the proof uses the definition with the modification that we don't need $\mathcal N \subseteq \mathcal T$, but only that each set in $\mathcal N$ is a neighbourhood. This definition makes some sense, because we also distinguish neighbourhoods and open neighbourhoods (it's also the definition given by Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_system#Basis)).

In this case, indeed the passage shows that each $U \in \mathcal N$ is a neighbourhood of zero, and if $V$ is an arbitrary neighbourhood of zero, we choose an open set $O \subseteq V$, and then $0 + U \subseteq O$ for some $U \in \mathcal N$ by the definition of open sets.

Let now $\tau$ be a translation-invariant topology such that $\mathcal N$ is a neighbourhood base of zero.

Let $O \in \tau$. We choose some $x \in O$. Then $0 \in O - x \in \tau$ (translation invariance), and thus we find $V \in \mathcal N$ such that $V \subseteq O - x$, and then $V + x \subseteq O$. Hence, $O \in \mathcal T$, and since $O \in \tau$ was arbitrary, $\tau \subseteq \mathcal T$.

If $O \in \mathcal T$, then
$$
O = \bigcup_{x \in O} (x + U_x),
$$
where $U_x \subseteq V_x$ is open in $\tau$ and $V_x \in \mathcal N$ such that $x + V_x \subseteq O$. Hence, $O \in \tau$ as the union of open sets.

Thus, $\tau = \mathcal T$.

Comment: $U_x$ is open in which topology?

Comment: $\tau$. This $U_x$ exists because $\mathcal N$ is a neighbourhood base by assumption.

Comment: @Jack: I just edited that.

Comment: In the last sentence of the second paragraph, do you mean $U\in\mathcal{N}$?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Will correct that. EDIT: Done.

Answer (score 0):

**Prologue**

Most common approaches to topology:

*The Point-Set Opens, the Hausdorff Neighborhoods and the Kuratowsky Closure.*
*(It turns out that they are all equivalent approaches.)*

They all come with their own advantages:

*The Point-Set Opens approach is best when investigating purely topological properties
 like compactness or connectedness as it stays in the realm of subsets not diving into points.*

*The Hausdorff Neighborhoods approach fits best when relating distinct points topologically
 like in Hausdorff spaces or topological vector spaces as it defines neighborhoods w.r.t points.*

*The Kuratowski Closure approach untangles relations to hull operators of other categories
 like the linear span or the orthogonal complement as it is a selfmap on power sets.*

Sometimes even a mixture is worthwhile like for locally compact spaces.

**Definition**

Given a plain space $\Omega$.

Consider $\mathcal{N}_x\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ for every $x\in\Omega$.
*(We call $\mathcal{N}_x$ the neighborhoods of $x\in\Omega$.)*

Every $\mathcal{N}_x$ should be a filter:
*If $N$ and $N'$ are neighborhoods of $x\in\Omega$ then so is $N\cap N'$*.
*If $N$ is a neighborhood of $x\in\Omega$ then so is $A$ for every $N\subseteq A$.*

Also $\mathcal{N}_x$ should be neighborhoods:
*Itself $\Omega$ is a neighborhood for every $x\in\Omega$.*
*If $N$ is a neigborhood of $x\in\Omega$ then so for every $z\in N_0$.*
*(There $N_0$ is a small enough neighborhood of $x\in\Omega$.)*