# continuity of the multiplication in a topological vector space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

This is a follow-up question related to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1438080/9464).
[image][image]

I don't follow the part of (joint) continuity of multiplication.

> My **question** is: how is it done in the proof?

---

Let $(\lambda_0,x_0)\in F\times X$ where $F$ is the underlying field $(\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C})$ and let $V\in\mathcal{N}$ such that $\lambda_0x_0\in \lambda_0x_0+V$. How should I find a neighborhood $W$ in $F\times X$ so that $\lambda x\in \lambda_0x_0+V$ for all $(\lambda,x)$?  [I was trying to follow the definition of continuity of a map between two topological spaces.]

---

The proof shows several things but I don't know how things are put together:

- For each $x\in X$, the map $\lambda\mapsto \lambda x$ is continuous at $\lambda=0$. [Fix $x\in X$. Let $V\in\mathcal{N}$ be a nbhd of $0$. Since $V$ is absorbing, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(\lambda-0)x\in V$ for all $\lambda$ with $|\lambda-0|<\delta$. This gives the desired continuity.]
- For each $\lambda\in F$, the map $x\to\lambda x$ is continuous at $x=0$.[To get $\lambda U\subset V$ as in the proof, one should also use the fact that $U$ is balanced. For example, consider $\lambda=1.5$. Also, I think in the proof, one should consider $|\lambda|\leq 2^n$ instead of $\lambda\leq 2^n$.]
- (Joint) continuity at $(0,0)$[? I don't get this part.]
- How the information above give the continuity at any $(\lambda,x)\in F\times X$?

Comment: Have you understood how the proof shows each of the three bullet points?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix any $(x_0,\lambda_0)\in X\times\mathbb R$ and consider any $V\in\mathcal N$. By applying (2) twice, there is some $U\in\mathcal N$ such that $$U+U+U+U\subseteq V.\tag{i}$$ Next, take $n\in\mathbb N$ so large that $|\lambda_0|+1\leq 2^n$ (I added $+1$ to ensure positivity). Again, applying (2) $n$ times, this time on $U$, one can find some $N\in\mathcal N$ such that $$(|\lambda_0|+1)N\subseteq U.\tag{ii}$$ (As you have already observed, one does need to consider absolute values, indeed, and also exploit the fact that every neighborhood in $\mathcal N$ is balanced by assumption.) Now, since $U$ is absorbing, there exists some $\alpha_0>0$ such that $$0\leq|\alpha|<\alpha_0\Rightarrow \alpha x_0\in U.\tag{iii}$$ Let $$\varepsilon\equiv\min\{\alpha_0,|\lambda_0|+1\}>0$$ and let $$W\equiv N\times(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon),$$ which is an open neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in the product topology on $X\times\mathbb R$ (the corresponding argument is very similar if $\mathbb F=\mathbb C$). I claim that if $(x-x_0,\lambda-\lambda_0)\in W$, then $\lambda x\in\lambda_0x_0+V$, which yields that the multiplication operator is continuous at any point in $X\times\mathbb R$, indeed. I will prove this claim in four steps.

**Step 1** Observe that if $(x-x_0,\lambda-\lambda_0)\in W$, then $x-x_0\in N$ and $|\lambda-\lambda_0|<\varepsilon$. Since $N$ is balanced, one has that $\beta(x-x_0)\in N$ whenever $|\beta|\leq 1$; so take $\beta\equiv\lambda_0/(|\lambda_0|+1)$. Then, (ii) implies that $$\lambda_0(x-x_0)\in(|\lambda_0|+1)N\subseteq U.$$

**Step 2** By a similar argument, given that $$|\lambda-\lambda_0|<\varepsilon\leq|\lambda_0|+1,$$ one has that $$(\lambda-\lambda_0)(x-x_0)\in(|\lambda_0|+1)N\subseteq U.$$

**Step 3** Since $$|\lambda-\lambda_0|<\varepsilon\leq\alpha_0,$$ (iii) implies that $$(\lambda-\lambda_0)x_0\in U.$$

**Step 4** Obviously, $0\in U$.

These four steps and (i) together imply that $$\lambda x-\lambda_0 x_0=\lambda_0(x-x_0)+(\lambda-\lambda_0)(x-x_0)+(\lambda-\lambda_0)x_0+0\in U+U+U+U\subseteq V,$$ as claimed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer in such a detail!  I'm still curious about how the original proof shows that joint continuity of the multiplication at $(0,0)$. For $V\in\mathcal{N}$ being a nbhd of $0$, one can take $W=V\times (-1,1)$ by the property of being balanced, right?

Comment: @Jack That’s right. If $(x,\lambda)\in V\times(-1,1)$, then $\lambda x\in V$, given that $V$ is balanced and $|\lambda|<1$. This shows that multiplication is continuous at the origin of the product space. This can be described also as $$V\times(-1,1)\subseteq\operatorname{Mult}^{-1}(V),$$ where $\operatorname{Mult}:X\times\mathbb R\to X$ is the multiplication operator. This shows that for any neighborhood $V\in\mathcal N$ of $0$, $\operatorname{Mult}^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in the product topology: This is exactly one definition (out of many) of continuity of a map at a point.

Comment: I'm wondering how the continuity of $\hbox{Mult}$ at $(0,0)$ is used in the original proof (i.e., the 4th bullet point in my question.) Your 4-step proof is much much clearer and readable (with which I'd like to "decipher" the quoted proof). If I understand correctly, Step 1 actually shows the continuity in the $x$ component for fixed $\lambda_0$ and Step 3 shows the continuity  in the $\lambda$ component for fixed $x_0$. More over, Step 2 can be the corollary of the (joint) continuity of  $\hbox{Mult}$ at $(0,0)$ with the translation invariance property of the topology on $X$. Am I right?

Comment: @Jack I don’t think the original proof ever directly exploits _joint_ continuity at the origin. It first proves _partial_ continuity of $x\mapsto\lambda x$ (for $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ fixed) at the point $x=0$, and the claims that “_[j]oint_ continuity of multiplication at _other_ points follows then from the continuity of addition [my italics]” and the decomposition presented at the end of the proof (which I further elaborate in my answer). I have the impression that the author expects the reader to work out the omitted details of this argument.

Comment: @Jack In my experience, omissions like this one are a common feature of mathematics textbooks, even good ones. The exposition is sometimes terse and the author expects the reader to do some of the work alone—sometimes this is indicated by “the details are left to the reader,” sometimes no such instructions are provided—especially if the omitted arguments are similar to previous ones already explained.

Comment: @Jack One last remark: Readers of textbooks may be prone to think that the author is a demigod, and blame themselves for having missed something if a particular argument comes across as fuzzy. In reality, textbook authors are human beings, too, and some of the arguments are just simply not-so-well-written. This happens occasionally even to the most outstanding writers and books. Indeed, some authors post errata on their website, which may be dozens of pages long, or rework some of the proofs in later editions and mention in the preface that “the proof of Theorem X.Y has been simplified.”

Comment: @Jack Correction to what I wrote earlier: I took another look at the proof and it actually does make sense to me now. Consider the decomposition: $$\lambda x-\lambda_0x_0=\lambda_0(x-x_0)+(\lambda-\lambda_0)x_0+(\lambda-\lambda_0)(x-x_{0}).$$ Now, the convergence of the last term (as $(\lambda-\lambda_0,x-x_0)\to(0,0)$) does follow from the joint continuity of addition at the origin. Convergence of the other two terms follows from separate continuity in each argument. Convergence of the summands implies convergence of the sum by virtue of the continuity of addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In light of your comments, I think one might consider the decomposition $$\lambda x-\lambda_0x_0=(\lambda-\lambda_0)x_0+(\lambda-0)(x-x_0)$$ instead to simplify the proof.

Comment: @Jack A problem with the simpler decomposition is that in the second term, $(\lambda-0,x-x_0)$ converges to $(\lambda_0,0)$, and we don’t know (yet) whether multiplication is _jointly_ continuous at $(\lambda_0,0)$; by the time we are considering the decomposition in the proof, only joint continuity at $(0,0)$ has been proven.